# Acceso remoto en servidor compartido

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Estoy usando un servidor compartido, para lo cual pensaba acceder a los archivos de mi web (Vía WinSCP) y a su base de datos (Vía Mysql-Workbench). En Workbench me arroja el error de acceso:

> Can't connect to MySQL server on 's985.tmd.cloud' (10061)

En Cpanel he agregado mi dirección de IP dentro de Remote MySQL, en Add Access Host Host (% wildcard is allowed)

Me he comunicado con el Soporte de mi servidor mas no logran ayudarme.

Cualquier sugerencia sería de utilidad.